# linux raid 1: right after replacing and syncing one drive, the other disk fails - understanding what is going on with mdstat/mdadm

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, drive-failure

We have an old RAID 1 Linux server (Ubuntu Lucid 10.04), with four partitions. A few days ago /dev/sdb failed, and today we noticed /dev/sda had pre-failure ominous SMART signs (~4000 reallocated sector count). We replaced /dev/sdb this morning and rebuilt the RAID on the new drive, following this guide:

http://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array

Everything went smooth until the very end. When it looked like it was finishing to synchronize the last partition, the other old one failed. At this point I am very unsure of the state of the system. Everything *seems* working and the files seem to be all accessible, just as if it synchronized everything, but I'm new to RAID and I'm worried about what is going on.

The /proc/mdstat output is:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md3 : active raid1 sdb4[2](S) sda4[0]
      478713792 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[2](F)
      244140992 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[2](F)
      244140992 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[2](F)
      9764800 blocks [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

The order of `[_U]` vs `[U_]`. Why aren't they consistent along all the array? Is the first `U` /dev/sda or /dev/sdb? (I tried looking on the web for this trivial information but I found no explicit indication) If I read correctly for md0, `[_U]` should be /dev/sda1 (down) and /dev/sdb1 (up). But if /dev/sda has failed, how can it be the *opposite* for md3 ? I understand /dev/sdb4 is now spare because probably it failed to synchronize it 100%, but why does it show /dev/sda4 as *up*? Shouldn't it be `[__]`? Or `[_U]` anyway? The /dev/sda drive now cannot even be accessed by SMART anymore apparently, so I wouldn't expect it to be up. What is wrong with my interpretation of the output?

I attach also the outputs of `mdadm --detail` for the four partitions:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 21 18:43:07 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 9764800 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9764800 (9.31 GiB 10.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Nov  5 17:27:33 2013
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : a3b4dbbd:859bf7f2:bde36644:fcef85e2
         Events : 0.7704

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

       2       8        1        -      faulty spare   /dev/sda1

/dev/md1:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 21 18:43:15 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 244140992 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 244140992 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Nov  5 17:39:06 2013
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 8bcd5765:90dc93d5:cc70849c:224ced45
         Events : 0.1508280

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2

       2       8        2        -      faulty spare   /dev/sda2


/dev/md2:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 21 18:43:19 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 244140992 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 244140992 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Nov  5 17:46:44 2013
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 2885668b:881cafed:b8275ae8:16bc7171
         Events : 0.2289636

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3

       2       8        3        -      faulty spare   /dev/sda3

/dev/md3:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Fri Jan 21 18:43:22 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 478713792 (456.54 GiB 490.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 478713792 (456.54 GiB 490.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Nov  5 17:19:20 2013
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      active sync   /dev/sda4
       1       0        0        1      removed

       2       8       20        -      spare   /dev/sdb4
```

The active sync on /dev/sda4 baffles me.

I am worried because if tomorrow morning I have to replace /dev/sda, I want to be sure what should I sync with what and what is going on. I am also quite baffled by the fact /dev/sda decided to fail *exactly* when the raid finished resyncing. I'd like to understand what is really happening.

Thanks a lot for your patience and help.

Massimo

Answer (score 1):

> **Q1:** The order of [*U] vs [U*]. Why aren't they consistent along all the array? Is the first U /dev/sda or /dev/sdb?

The order is based on the RaidDevice numbers. These are the numbers in the square brackets of the lines like this:

```
md3 : active raid1 sdb4[2](S) sda4[0]
      478713792 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[2](F)
      244140992 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[2](F)
      244140992 blocks [2/1] [_U]

...
```

For md3 the sda4 device is #0. The sdb4 device is #2. So the U is for the sba4 device. For md2 the U is for device sda3, #2. So it would seem that you drive sdb is one one having the issues, since none of those partitions is listed as "UP" aka. "U". They'are all reported as "DOWN" aka. "_".

> **Q2:** Shouldn't it be [__]? Or [_U] anyway?

The output from `/proc/mdstat` should be all `[UU]`'s aka. they're all "UP". For example here's my RAID1 array, with 2 members.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      976759936 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

#### References

- [Mdstat](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat)